# Position XAML child by location and size

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I want to set the location (x and y) of a child element, and its size (width and height). I can't find a way to do that. If I set a Grid's Margins - I can't set only Left and Top, I must also set Right and Bottom along with them. And if I use an AbsoluteLayout instead of a Grid, it takes up a large amount of CPU use.

So is there any way to specify location and size (as in Winforms) or is UWP simply not advanced enough for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute positioning like this is a very problematic thing, as apps need to run on devices of wide variety of screen sizes and can be resized anytime by the user. If you use absolute positioning, you need to know for sure that you will have such dimensions available.

For absolute positioning you can use `Canvas`. You can then use `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Right` attached properties to specify positions and `Height` and `Width` to specify size, for example:

```
<Canvas>
   <Button Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="20" Width="200" Height="120" />
   <Rectangle Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="50" Width="64" Height="20" Fill="Blue" />
</Canvas>
```

On the other hand, using relative layout controls is still preferable in most cases. `Grid` allows you to specify rows/columns as well as spacing among them and relative sizes using star notation.